# cron to be setup

Tags: php, cron

I have an already setted up cron job. Now i have a file whose cron i have to setup such that my file should run at 9:00 am,11:00am,1:00pm,5:00pm and 7:00pm

Idont have much idea about cron So can anyone please help me in setting up this cron for my file at the aboove given timings !!

Comment: hi so if my solution helped can you select it as the accepted answer

Comment: yes Saeros your answer was really helpful and so it deserves to be the best answer :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format for the CRON Jobs is:

```
minute hour dom month dow user cmd
```

---

**minute**  This controls what minute of the hour the command will run on,
     and is between '0' and '59'

---

**hour**    This controls what hour the command will run on, and is specified in
         the 24 hour clock, values must be between 0 and 23 (0 is midnight)

---

**dom** This is the Day of Month, that you want the command run on, e.g. to
     run a command on the 19th of each month, the dom would be 19.

---

**month**   This is the month a specified command will run on, it may be specified
     numerically (0-12), or as the name of the month (e.g. May)

---

**dow** This is the Day of Week that you want a command to be run on, it can
     also be numeric (0-7) or as the name of the day (e.g. sun).

---

**user**    This is the user who runs the command.

---

**cmd** This is the command that you want run. This field may contain 
     multiple words or spaces.

---

If you don't wish to specify a value for a field, just place a * in the 
field.

---

Here is an example of how a crontab is setup.

```
01 * * * * root echo "This command is run at one min past every hour"
17 8 * * * root echo "This command is run daily at 8:17 am"
17 20 * * * root echo "This command is run daily at 8:17 pm"
00 4 * * 0 root echo "This command is run at 4 am every Sunday"
* 4 * * Sun root echo "So is this"
42 4 1 * * root echo "This command is run 4:42 am every 1st of the month"
01 * 19 07 * root echo "This command is run hourly on the 19th of July"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Each of the positions means a specific thing:**

1. Minute [0,59]
2. Hour [0,23]
3. Day of the month [1,31]
4. Month of the year [1,12]
5. Day of the week ([0,6] with 0=Sunday)

For example:

`0 9,11,13,17,19 * * *   /bin/whatever >> /some/log/if/you/want/it.log`

**In English:**

Run /bin/whatever on the 0th minute of the 9th, 11th, 13th, 17th, and 19th hour of every day, of every month, each day of the week.

Comment: okk i got it....but this is written in this cron file for some other files 
*/3 22,23,0-7 * * 0-5 /bin/whatever

what does this mean then???

Answer (score 0):

`0 9,11,13,17,19 * * * something`

`man 5 crontab`